# What does Rubinius.primitive do?

Tags: rubinius

I'm reading through the [Rubinius source code](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius), and I keep coming across methods that go something like this:

```
def self.do_something
  Rubinius.primitive :vm_do_something
  raise SomeError, "primitive failed to do something"
end
```

For example, [kernel/alpha.rb](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/alpha.rb) and [kernel/bootstrap/rubinius.rb](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/37db25344701e52c92b53be4f136ba5b175f6138/kernel/bootstrap/rubinius.rb) both have a lot of these. They're all over the place, and I can't seem to find where `Rubinius.primitive` is defined.
Since I have no idea what it does, I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how Rubinius gets stuff done.

Comment: So I went on IRC at freenode.net #rubinius, and learned that the behavior of `Rubinius.primitive` is to replace the method it's called in with a call to C++ code. The calls to `raise` that commonly follow calls to `primitive` are only executed if `primitive` somehow fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went on IRC at `freenode.net` `#rubinius`, and learned that the behavior of `Rubinius.primitive` is to replace the method it's called in with a call to C++ code. The calls to raise that commonly follow calls to primitive are only executed if primitive somehow fails.